# Does drinking milk as an adult cause calcium loss from bones?

Tags: nutrition, milk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does drinking milk lead to osteoporosis?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/150/does-drinking-milk-lead-to-osteoporosis)

The [Save Our Bones](http://saveourbones.com/osteoporosis-milk-myth/) claims that drinking milk is bad for your bones:

> the most surprising link is that not only do we barely absorb the calcium in cow’s milk (especially if pasteurized), but to make matters worse, it actually increases calcium loss from the bones. What an irony this is!
>   Here’s how it happens. Like all animal protein, milk acidifies the body pH which in turn triggers a biological correction. You see, calcium is an excellent acid neutralizer and the biggest storage of calcium in the body is – you guessed it… in the bones. So the very same calcium that our bones need to stay strong is utilized to neutralize the acidifying effect of milk. Once calcium is pulled out of the bones, it leaves the body via the urine, so that the surprising net result after this is an actual calcium deficit.

It cites the Harvard Nurses’ Health Study for evidence.

Is this true?

Comment: Closed because it had a duplicate but it got deleted?!?